# Gradient button bar like the one found in Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

The bar I’m looking for is the separator bar between the editor area and the debug area:

[image]

Specifically, I want the buttons to have no borders and I want to have the vertical separator (to the left of ‘No Selection’).

I haven’t done any AppKit stuff in Mountain Lion yet, so before I start implementing my own custom control, I was wondering if I have overlooked a new control (or options for existing controls), or otherwise if somebody has already implemented a custom control that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just NSButtons with a custom background image (which is the silver effect) and the "Image" which is the control image.

A quick look inside Xcode.app/Contents/OtherFrameworks/DevToolsInterface.framework/Versions/A/Resources will show you the relevant images.

Comment: It actually appears to be the images in `Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Resources/com.apple.dt.IDEKit.*.pdf`, but yes that does appear to be what they’re doing. Ok, I know enough, thanks!

Comment: Ah I think there may be multiple copies of it as I saw the ButtonBackground.tiff file had the silver effect, either way, glad I could help!